# hide widget from ui without taking any space

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a code like below, I want to hide the subtitle text using if, but when the subtitle is hidden, it adds empty space under the title, but if the subtitle text is removed, it will work fine

[image]

```
Column(
  children : [
    SizedBox(height: AppTheme.space1),
    Image.asset(
      image,
      width: 128,
      height: 128,
    ),
    SizedBox(height: AppTheme.space2),
    Text(
      title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    if (subTitle != null)
      SizedBox(height: AppTheme.space0),
    if (subTitle != null)
      Text(
        subTitle ?? '',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
      ),
    SizedBox(height: AppTheme.space3),
    Button(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, returnTextYes);
        onTapPrimaryButton?.call();
      },
      text: textYes,
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Visibility` Widget

```
bool isVisible = subtitle.isNotEmpty

Visibility(
visible:isVisible
child: Text(
          subTitle ?? '',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
        )
)
```